# Remove item from PHP Array - only from master group

Tags: php, arrays

I need to search and than remove specific times from **Tennis 1** and **Padel 1** Resource.

My array is like this,

```
array(2) {
    ["Tennis 1"] => array(1) {
        ["IntervalTime"] => array(7) {
            ["Lun"] => array(11) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "10:00" [1] => string(5)
                "11:00" [2] => string(5)
                "12:00" [3] => string(5)
                "13:00" [4] => string(5)
                "14:00" [5] => string(5)
                "15:00" [6] => string(5)
                "16:00" [7] => string(5)
                "17:00" [8] => string(5)
                "18:00" [9] => string(5)
                "19:00" [10] => string(5)
                "20:00"
            }["Mar"] => array(4) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "12:00" [1] => string(5)
                "13:00" [2] => string(5)
                "14:00" [3] => string(5)
                "15:00"
            }["Mer"] => array(5) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00"
            }["Gio"] => array(5) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00"
            }["Ven"] => array(5) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00"
            }["Sab"] => array(10) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00" [5] => string(5)
                "14:00" [6] => string(5)
                "15:00" [7] => string(5)
                "16:00" [8] => string(5)
                "17:00" [9] => string(5)
                "18:00"
            }["Sun"] => array(10) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00" [5] => string(5)
                "14:00" [6] => string(5)
                "15:00" [7] => string(5)
                "16:00" [8] => string(5)
                "17:00" [9] => string(5)
                "18:00"
            }
        }
    }["Padel 1"] => array(1) {
        ["IntervalTime"] => array(7) {
            ["Lun"] => array(2) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "11:00" [1] => string(5)
                "12:00"
            }["Mar"] => array(2) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "14:00" [1] => string(5)
                "15:00"
            }["Mer"] => array(1) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "11:00"
            }["Gio"] => array(8) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "11:00" [1] => string(5)
                "12:00" [2] => string(5)
                "13:00" [3] => string(5)
                "14:00" [4] => string(5)
                "15:00" [5] => string(5)
                "16:00" [6] => string(5)
                "17:00" [7] => string(5)
                "18:00"
            }["Ven"] => array(1) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "11:00"
            }["Sab"] => array(1) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "11:00"
            }["Sun"] => array(10) {
                [0] => string(5)
                "09:00" [1] => string(5)
                "10:00" [2] => string(5)
                "11:00" [3] => string(5)
                "12:00" [4] => string(5)
                "13:00" [5] => string(5)
                "14:00" [6] => string(5)
                "15:00" [7] => string(5)
                "16:00" [8] => string(5)
                "17:00" [9] => string(5)
                "18:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The targets to delete are:

```
Tennis 1 ---> "Mer" ---> "11:00" and "12:00"
Padel 1 ---> "Gio" ---> "12:00" and "14:00".
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unset` or `array_filter`,

```
    foreach($array["Tennis 1"]["IntervalTime"]["Mar"] as $index => &$value){
        if($value == "11:00" || $value == "12:00"){
            unset($array["Tennis 1"]["IntervalTime"]["Mar"][$index]);
        }
    }
    foreach($array["Padel 1"]["IntervalTime"]["Gio"] as $index => $value){
        if($value == "12:00" || $value == "14:00"){
            unset($array["Padel 1"]["IntervalTime"]["Gio"][$index]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've tried, but the result is the same. Items isn't removed.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6a307162500642e6718d1b17e2a4329e09c819d

Comment: I didn't realise that time is value not a key. I've edited my answer, check it http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1075b6d03fab6e49e26c1303495700e3ec1b58f.

Answer (score 0):

Try `unset($array['Tennis 1']['Mer']['11:00']);` and `unset($array['Tennis 1']['Mer']['12:00']);`

Comment: targets are the hours, not the resources.

Comment: Then do `unset($array['Tennis 1']['Mer']['11:00']);`, etc. You can add as many keys in there to match the right item.